# Why doesn't Python make list/tuple/dict/set generic?

Tags: python, typing

In Python, the `typing` module provides generic versions of builtin containers, such as `Dict`, `List`, etc. Why do this rather than just making the builtins generic?

For example, we use

```
typing.List[int]
```

Why doesn't Python just allow this?:

```
list[int]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generic versions of containers"? `list` and `dict` are already generics, in some sense: you can put _any_ object in a list, use any hashable object as a key of a dictionary and again _any_ object as a value. Moreover, both can hold multiple objects of different types at the same time. Even more, it's not even possible to instantiate `typing.List`, so I'm not sure what you're talking about...

Comment: @ForceBru I think the question is *why should we `typing.List` instead of `list` in type hinting?* as far as I can understand.

Comment: Potentially to avoid needing to modify all the classes involved. It's likely more maintainable to have the types defined [like they are](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e8692818afd731c1b7e925c626ac8200b1f1c31e/Lib/typing.py#L1465), rather than having changes across multiple files. Unless `list` could be "decorated" after the fact.

Comment: the question is a bit misleading. python containers are *already generic*, indeed, python is not a statically typed language, so all containers are heterogenous, typing is generally 'duck typing'. You are asking how to *properly annotate a generic container*. for that, you must use the `typing` module.

Comment: 'Generic' in Python means the type can be subscripted. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html for more information.